# Magento 2 - Increase customer session timeout for inactivity

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, customer, customer-account, customer-session

**Customer gets logged out after *30 mins* of inactivity. I want to increase it to *1 hour*. Any idea how to that?**

Answer (score 1):

**Stores > Settings > Configuration -> General -> Web -> Default Cookie Settings**

By default, the cookie lifetime is set to 3600 seconds, or one hour. If there is no keyboard activity during that time, the current session ends, and customers must log back into their accounts to continue shopping.

You interested in Session Cookie, but if customer session expire that is set in php.ini your customer cookie could expire also.

Look into:

**session.gc_maxlifetime =**

and

**session.cookie_lifetime =**

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/customers/customer-online-options.html?itm_source=merchdocs_ce&itm_medium=quick_search&itm_campaign=federated_search&itm_term=customers%20s

and PHP

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes